# c++ library in C# IOS project in Visual studio

Tags: c#, c++, xamarin.ios

I have created a C++ static library for ios (XCode 6.1) in visual studio. But when I compile this project, the output .a file is getting created in Mac machine and not getting copied back to Windows. My concern is that how can I refer this static library in an iOS C# application project in Visual studio?

Comment: `not getting copied back to Windows` - Can you clarify this? not sure how you are trying to reference this in the Xamarin.iOS app from visual studio

Comment: @dalexsoto, After the compilation process finished, the output .a file is generated in Mac machine, not in Windows. So I would like to know how can I reference this static library generated in Mac machine into the iOS visual studio project in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have several options here, what you need to do is to have a Dll that contains the native .a library and the resources/code to interop with the native c++ library (and reference that Dll in your Visual Studio Xamarin.iOS project). You can use a Xamarin iOS Binding project as a container and one of the following options

- You can use [swig](http://www.swig.org) to wrap the c++ lib and there is actually a video from [Xamarin University lighting lectures from Chris Van Wyk](https://university.xamarin.com/lightninglectures/ios-bindings-in-cc) that describes the process.
- You can use [Mono CppSharp](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp) to wrap the library (My personal favourite easier to use than swig).
- You can write your own c wrapper around the c++ library and P/Invoke that from C#
- You can write your own Objective-C wrapper around the c++ library and use a Xamarin.iOS Binding project to interop with it.

  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I will try Swig, as the video is very much explaining step by step how to use swig for C/C++ library to use in iOS

Comment: No problem at all, hope that gets you started :)

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this post. I am having exactly the same problem as @Rahim that libs are not "downloaded" to my windows.

In fact I created my own C wrapper and hand P/Invoking the C code. 
My problem stems from the fact that I cannot tell VS Xamarin project that it should link with my VC++ Ios lib. Any clues ?